# Data Grid no muestra datos VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, lista

Hola buenas noches queria pedir ayuda, tengo armado una consulta a un archivo de excel, el cual funciona la conexión, pero a la hora de hacer el `SELECT * FROM`, me aparecen todas las columnas en el datagridview pero no aparecen los datos...
Quería saber si a alguno le pasó y como solucionarlo.
Paso código.

```
Public Sub prueba123()
    Dim nombretabla As String
    Using conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Programador\Desktop\Compartido\Datos_Precios_20180904.xlsx; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR= YES"";")
        Try
            conn.Open()
            Using dt As DataTable = conn.GetSchema("Tables")
                Dim query As IEnumerable(Of String) =
                        From row As DataRow In dt.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)()
                        Where CStr(row.Item("TABLE_TYPE")).ToUpperInvariant() = "TABLE"
                        Select CStr(row.Item("TABLE_NAME"))
                'Order By row.Item("TABLE_NAME")
                nombretabla = query.ToList(0)
            End Using

            Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * from [" + nombretabla + "]", conn)
                Dim dta As New DataTable
                cmd.Fill(dta)
                'dta.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
                frmPreciosImportar.DataGridView1.DataSource = dta
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias y buenas noches!

Comment: ya revisaste si dta tiene registros?, si todo se está ejecutando bien hasta "cmd.Fill(dta)" entonces cambio la pregunta, tiene tu DataGridView1 columnas predefinidas o está vacía? si ya tienes columnas predefinidas entonces tendrás que espcificar el nombre de la columna dentro de dta que debe estar vinculada a la columna de tu grid, ve a la columna de tu grid y revisa la propiedad DataPropertyName, ahi debe estar el nombre de la columna de dta con la que se deberá enlazar

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes tu tabla de datos en Excel? He probado el código y con datos sin ningún formato me va perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por responder. mi datagridview1 no tiene columnas predefinidas. Intenté probando con el datagridview ya predefinido y tampoco funcionó...
El dta se llena de columnas pero no de Rows. En count aparece 0. No entiendo por qué pasa ésto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla de excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán tengo muchisimos registros, pero en el Form solo aparecen las columnas..